# How combine one string and variable for new variable

Tags: php, variables, foreach, set

$i18ncoches="coches";
$i18nmotos="motos";

Hi I am trying to create a variable from a foreach, combining a string and a variable

```
$apartados=array('coches', 'motos', 'naves', 'avion');

foreach ($apartados as $key) {
    echo $i18n.$key;

}
```

but the expected result is to leave the following

```
$i18ncoches
$i18nmotos
```

but get the following
Notice: Undefined variable: i18n

```
coches motos etc,,,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php

    $i18ncoches="coches";
    $i18nmotos="motos";

    $apartados=array('coches', 'motos', 'naves', 'avion');

    foreach ($apartados as $key) {

       // if(isset(${'i18n'.$key})) //you will need this check 
             echo ${'i18n'.$key};

    }

?>
```

Comment: thanks, and tried to look quite the solution and this is the one sought